# "Fix text pasted into string literals" - what does it do?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

What does the following setting do in Visual Studio?

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Editor Help > Fix text pasted into string literals (experimental)

[image]

I didn't see it "fix" things I paste into a `"   "`. Perhaps in certain cases?

Answer (score 3):

This attempts to escape characters inserted into string literals that are not legal there, such as quotes or single backspaces. Unfortunately, the option pages are very poorly documented. The [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-advanced?view=vs-2022) states

> Not all options may be listed here.

Which, at least, is honest...

Answer (score 0):

This option (I have now turned it off) was adding a \ character before pasted text when pasting at the end of a string. In my case, this happened when using a StringBuilder.
For Example:

```
sb.AppendLine(" ,'NA' as CheckedDate
```

Desired Code after pasting "); at the end

```
sb.AppendLine(" ,'NA' as CheckedDate ");
```

Resultant code after pasting with this option turned on

```
sb.AppendLine(" ,'NA' as CheckedDate \");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this when pasting text that contained a quotation mark, VS 2022 kept escaping the quotation (adding "\")

Fixed by going into  Tools -> Options --> Text Editor --> Advanced and unchecking "Use adaptive formatting"

Comment: That didn't do anything for me. The fix for me was to uncheck: Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Editor Help > Fix text pasted into string literals (experimental)